# Content Security Policy multiple nonce

Tags: javascript, html, content-security-policy, nonce, websecurity

I have a single page application (built in .net core MVC 2.2), where html section are loaded on the fly.

On main document, added CSP policy with a dynamically generated header looks like:

```
Content-Security-Policy: script-src 'self' 'nonce-I64vb811BxRNGV9Xf0pM'
```

Then comes a page section loaded via jquery ajax load function. page section contains a script (from src) with a nonce. Page section served with CSP header looks like

```
Content-Security-Policy: script-src 'self' 'nonce-ci5TQsyidT8x2jwBLRHS'
```

all good but browsers (chrome, safari blocking the script), with message:

```
jqueryscriptsbundle.js:formatted:43 Refused to execute inline script 
because it violates the following 
Content Security Policy directive: "script-src 'self' 'nonce-I64vb811BxRNGV9Xf0pM'
```

So browser is comparing nonce of script i.e. ci5TQsyidT8x2jwBLRHS with root/main page nonce value I64vb811BxRNGV9Xf0pM hence script blocked.

Is it correct behavior ? What can I do to make it work?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your initial CSP, loaded with the page, provides a nonce. What you're trying to do is add another nonce, via Ajax, after the initial page load. CSP explicitly doesn't allow this; that's not a bug -- it's the entire point.

What you might do is allow a script-src of `strict-dynamic`. This allows you to authorize a script, and anything loaded by that script is also authorized.  See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Security-Policy/script-src

Comment: To be clear: it may be better to link the script from your main page rather than loading new scripts. It *is* less secure to use strict-dynamic; but certainly not as bad as unsafe-inline.... Within the Ajax function itself you can, after load, link existing scripts to the new content

Comment: Thanks for headup, what do you mean by link existing script to new content? How would you do that?

Comment: You know how you normally link scripts to (for example) `onclick` events when the page loads?  You can do that as part of the Ajax function as well -- add the new content, and *then* link scripts to that content

Comment: Would be difficult to do. Strict-dynamic is not supported in safari. Thanks

Comment: The point is that if you do it that way, you don't *need* strict-dynamic, because the code is on your main page and not coming from Ajax content. Your specific case may not work this way, but there's a good chance it can

Comment: True that but I am not getting you about linking part, at best I can put an Init method in all js and call init method, according to page module, as an second option, I am thinking about making use of session to keep same nonce for single session.

Comment: I know this is a late response, but: NO! Don't do anything that keeps a nonce for multiple uses.  You're defeating the purpose of a nonce. (The word is literally a portmanteau of "number" and "once". Use it twice and it's not a nonce; and it's *not secure*.)

Comment: Then what alternatives we can try to support different multiple nonces